# DOM parser in java not encoding quotes in UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am trying to use the code available from this tutorial :http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

I've pasted the code below as well, the problem it seems to encode all the predef characters <,> and & etc. but not single or double quotes (" and '). I'd really appreciate a fix. Also the code below has an edit to make the resultant xml appear properly formatted

More specifically:

```
     import java.io.File;
   import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
       import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
     import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
        import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
      import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
      import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
        import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

       import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
   import org.w3c.dom.Document;
   import org.w3c.dom.Element;

 public class WriteXMLFile {

public static void main(String argv[]) {

  try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    // staff elements
    Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

    // set attribute to staff element
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

    // shorten way
    // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

    // firstname elements
    Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
    firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
    staff.appendChild(firstname);

    // lastname elements
    Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
    lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
    staff.appendChild(lastname);

    // nickname elements
    Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
    nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
    staff.appendChild(nickname);

    // salary elements
    Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
    salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
    staff.appendChild(salary);

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File saved!");

  } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: add this in your code transformerFactory.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

Comment: Still does not work for apostrophe and quotes, works for everything else.

Comment: Seems fine to me, could you give specific example of how it's failing?

Comment: If I put in double quote in anything e.g firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yo\"ng")); It simply appears as a quote in the XML

Comment: @user1011689: Quotes are note required to be escaped in text content, that would only be needed in attributes using the same quoting character.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine. Put a double quote in an attribute value and see what happens.

Comment: If I put in double quote in anything e.g
 firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yo\"ng"));
It simply appears as a quote in the XML

Comment: Have you tried it in the `attribute` value like I mentioned? What I'm getting at is that the quote is fine in the `element` value.

Answer (score 0):

Read [section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax) of the XML specification. Production 14 of the grammar

```
[14]    CharData       ::=      [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

tells you that character data can be any (valid XML) character except '<' and '&' (or the ']]>' sequence).  It is not strictly necessary to escape '>', although recommended.